# Remove invalid broker Information from Replicas in kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, replication, apache-zookeeper

I was trying to increase the replication factor of a topic by providing a json as specified in docs.

https://kafka.apache.org/0102/documentation.html

By mistake i put invalid broker id in specifying replication list.
Even if did the rollback, that invalid broker id is not going off.

Is there a way to fix it.
Please help

`Topic: cms_scf_images_zip  Partition: 16   Leader: 4   Replicas: 4,6,7,8 Isr: 4,6,7
Topic: cms_scf_images_zip   Partition: 17   Leader: 5   Replicas: 5,7,1 Isr: 5,7,1`

**8 is the invalid broker id**

Answer (score 0):

I posted a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430936/kafka-how-to-remove-broker-from-replica-set/45579676#45579676).

Spin up a new broker with an id of 8.

Using ./kafka-topics.sh check that node 8 is in the **isr** column.

Once it is sync'd, you can use ./kafka-reassign-partitions.sh to remove it as a replica.